# Why is this xpath expression not working?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Scrapy is a web crawler and I have created a spider.
I want the spider to create 2 html files with the body of the 2 links.
The html files created are empty.

```
    import scrapy
    from scrapy.selector import Selector
    from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

    class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "dmoz"
        allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
        start_urls = [
       "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
       "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
]

        def parse(self, response):
            x=response.xpath("//body/text()").extract()
            filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(x)
```

Answer (score -1):

Please revisit the [Scrapy tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.1/intro/tutorial.html) and double-check; your example is basically a verbatim copy of `dmoz_spider.py`.

First of all, note that `xpath()` returns a selector list. Calling `extract()` on the selector list gives you a list of unicode strings, which you can't write into a file as is. You need to join the strings and encode the result (e.g. using UTF-8).

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(u"".join(x).encode("UTF-8"))
```

As to why it's not working now: You use an XPath expression to select all text nodes of the body element. As the text nodes only contain whitespace characters, the created files appear to be empty.

The result of `response.xpath("//body/text()").extract()` is `[u'\r\n\r\n  ', u'\r\n\r\n  ', u'\r\n\r\n  ', u'\r\n\r\n    ', u'\r\n\r\n  ', u'\r\n\r\n    ', u'\r\n\r\n    ', u'\r\n    ', u'\r\n    ', u'\r\n\r\n  ', u'\r\n\r\n    ', u'\r\n\r\n  ', u'\r\n\r\n    ', u'\r\n\r\n  ', u'\r\n\r\n  ']`, so your files should contain some whitespace characters.

To select all nodes below the body element, use `response.xpath("//body/node())`.

To e.g. select all `div` elements having the class `hero`, use `response.xpath("//div[@class = 'hero']")`.

And perhaps you should first read some basic tutorial on XPath. Learning by doing will not work here, you really need to get the basics straight first.

Comment: what other xpath expression would work to copy the body.I tried response.xpath("//body").extract() and it didnt work.I know response.body works but I want to learn xpath.

Comment: It would help if you would clarify your question as to what exactly you expect to end up in the HTML files. If you just want them to be written to disc as returned by the server, you don't need XPath at all.

Comment: I want the html files to contain the body elements.Once that works I am going to collect all div elements with a specific class.

Comment: Your code makes sense to me but the files are still empty.

Comment: Well, you can't just pass a list of unicode strings to `write()`. See updated answer.

Comment: how did you know that ? How to make sure  I can solve problems like these without other people's help in the future ?

Comment: The Scrapy reference documentation told me what I needed to know regarding `x`. The Python documentation states that `f.write()` takes a `str` object, and not a list of unicode strings. So basically it's just reading the docs and putting the info together.